# Showing triangle is closed from definition

Tags: real-analysis

Let $A=\{(x_1,x_2) : x_1\in [0,1], x_2\in [0,1-x_1] \}$. I want to show that $A$ is closed using the definition, i.e by showing that $A^c$ is open. The part I'm struggling with is if we take $y\in A^c \cap \{(x_1,x_2):x_1,x_2>0\}$. Taking $r=\frac{1}{2} \text{dist}(y,A)$ should work such that $B_r(y) \subseteq A^c$, but I'm not sure how to show this properly. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Hint: write out what $y \not\in A$ means. You will then get two cases, in both of which you can find an $r > 0$ such that $B_r(y) \cap A = \emptyset$. Thinking about $ \text{dist}(y,A)$ doesn't help much as you have to prove that it is non-zero and that only falls out from the argument I have just suggested.

Comment: Whenever it's possible, draw a picture. These open balls, distances, inequalities, are much easier to write down once you're looking at a picture. Play with [this interactive graphic](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/yc5erxrqiv) where you drag the point around and see it's distance to the triangle and the open disk around the point of half that distance.

Comment: With these sorts of sets it can be easier if you're happy to appeal to a few nice lemmas about closed/open sets and continuous functions: since $A = \{(x_1, x_2) : 0 \le x_1 \le 1, 0 \le x_2 \le 1 - x_1\}$, consider the function $f: \Bbb R^2 \to \Bbb R^3$ defined by $f(x_1, x_2) = (x_1, x_2, x_1 + x_2)$. Then $A = f^{-1}([0, 1] \times [0, \infty) \times (-\infty, 1])$. So $A$ is the continuous preimage of a closed set, and is hence closed. The proofs of all facts used here are constructive, so you can extract an elementary argument by "following the proof"!

Comment: @IzaakvanDongen I do like this approach, but that's not what is intended with the exercise. It is supposed to be done more naïvely, assuming you only know the definition of an open set.

Comment: @RobArthan That's a good point!

Comment: I get that! I thought I'd mention it because it can help to know "what's really going on". But also, my last sentence means you can extract such an elementary proof from this argument: "Suppose $(x_1, x_2) \notin A$. Then $(x_1, x_2, x_1 + x_2) \notin [0, 1] \times [0, \infty) \times (-\infty, 1]$. So let $r$ be small enough that upon perturbing $(x_1, x_2)$ by $r$, $(x_1, x_2, x_1 + x_2)$ is still not in $[0, 1] \times [0, \infty) \times (-\infty, 1]$." (details omitted here :)). If you're really stuck with an elementary proof, it can sometimes help to generalise and then re-specialise!